# Ajax.BeginForm() Action is not fired

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, ajaxform

This is my View.cshtml

```
<h3>Search One Drive</h3>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("test", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "result" }))    
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Search</legend>

    <div id="result"></div>
    <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.queryTerm)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.queryTerm)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.queryTerm)
        </div>
</fieldset>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</p>
}
```

I have a corresponding ActionResult in my Home Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult test(Model testModel)
        {
            string query = testModel.queryTerm;
            return Content("hi " + query);
        }
```

It is a MVCV4 web app with razor. So, when I get to the view page and enter a query and hover over "Submit", I see Home/test method get display (upon hover). But when I click on Submit, the control is not passed on the ActionResult test() in the HomeController.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show complete controller

Comment: I am a little concerned you have chosen to use `Model` as the parameter. Can you show your view model code and the full view source including the `@model` declartion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this was the fix:

I did not have a parameterless constructor in my Model Class. So, when this call was being made, it was unable to create an instance. Once, I added the default constructor, it started functioning well.

Fixed this with the help of Fiddler.